# How do I find the marginal pdfs given the following random vectors?

Tags: probability, statistics

$\begin{bmatrix} Y{_1}\\Y{_2} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&3\\1&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} X{_1}\\X{_2} \end{bmatrix}$

Given the random vectors above, with $X{_1}$, $X{_2}$ being two independent gaussian distributed random variables, how do I find the marginal pdfs for $f{_Y{_1}}$and $f{_Y{_2}}$ ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! As this site is meant to be a useful repository rather than a Do My Homework forum, it's common courtesy to show what you've already tried, and really narrow down what you're struggling with. Most people here are glad to help once you've adequately motivated the problem. [Quick Guide](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813) to attracting answers and preventing your question from being deleted. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Follows $Y_1=1/2 X_1+3 X_2$ and $Y_2=X_1+X_2$, with $X_1$ and $X_2$ being independent gaussians with $E(X_i)=\mu_i$, $V(X_i)=\sigma^2_i$, $i\in \{1,2\}$.

Therefore, given that any linear combination of gaussians is gaussian, the marginals for $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are also gaussians, with
$$E(Y_1)=1/2 \mu_1+3 \mu_2,\ \ \ V(Y_2)=1/4 \sigma^2_1+ 9\sigma_2^2$$
$$E(Y_2)= \mu_1+ \mu_2,\ \ \ V(Y_2)= \sigma^2_1+\sigma_2^2$$

A more interestion question is finding $\text{Cov}(Y_1,Y_2)$. As an exercise, show that
$$\text{Cov}(Y_1,Y_2)=1/2 \sigma^2_1+3\sigma_2^2$$
and define the joint distribution for $(Y_1,Y_2)$.